# Merge sorting an array with a size that is not 2^n

Tags: sorting, mergesort

In every example of merge sort I have found, the algorithm is demonstrated on an array of size 8 or some other power of 2. This makes it easier to demonstrate, but doesn’t explain how to employ it on arrays of different sizes. How should you split up the sub arrays?

Comment: A basic merge sort will just take an "extra" pass, worst case would be a size of (2^n) + 1, where it would take n+1 passes, the last pass merging a sorted run of size 2^n with a sorted run of size 1. Some variations of merge sort will use something like in place insertion sort on the initial pass to create small sorted runs of size k, where k could range from say 8 to 64 or so, and k chosen to have an even number of merge sort passes and avoid having a relatively small last run on the final merge passes.

Comment: For example for n = 1025, choose k = 17. After the initial in place pass to create sorted runs of size 17, there will be 6 merge passes. Run counts and sizes for the initial pass and the 6 merge passes: {60*17 + 1*5}, {30*34 + 1*5}, {15*68 + 1*5}, {7*136 + 1*73}, {3*272 + 1*209}, {1*544 + 1*481}, {1*1025}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this problem. In the classical version of mergesort you continue breaking the input down until you have single-element sub-collections, which are by definition sorted - then you start merging the sub-collections back together. Breaking the collection down into single-element collections is mostly an exercise in allocating memory/creating collection objects and sticking one element in each.

The basic merge-sort function doesn't actually do very much at all. My Clojure (Lisp variant) implementation of mergesort looks like:

```
(defn merge-sort [compare-func col]
  (merge-runs compare-func (find-runs-of-3 compare-func col)))
```

In other words, the input collection `col` is broken down into sub-collections of three elements and sorted, and then these three element subcollections are merged to get the final output. If the input collection isn't an exact multiple of three elements, that's OK - it just means there's going to be a "leftover" sub-collection of 1 or 2 elements to be sorted/merged in with all the rest.

(As to "why collections-of-three" - efficiency. First, breaking the collection to be sorted down into collections-of-1 requires three times more effort than breaking it down into collections-of-3. Then, too, you can sort a three-element collection using, on average, 2.66 comparisons instead of three, which saves 1/3 of a comparison for each sub-collection. Not much of a savings, perhaps, until you're sorting collections of 50K elements :-).

Best of luck.

Comment: As an alternative, the first pass could sort pairs of elements by swapping in place, averaging 1 compare and 0.5 swaps per pair.